# Django: Ajax call not working in chrome. Working in firefox

Tags: html, ajax, django, post, django-views

UPDATE: I have found the problem (I think). I don't think this is a browser problem per se, but rather a speed problem. When I print out the csrftoken via:

```
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
console.log(csrftoken)
```

in my local machine I get the token in the console. On my live version though, the toke is null. I'll make a new question for this, as the actual question has changed quite a bit.

EDITS: On the advice of a friend, I have put the input and button into a form with a {$ csrf_token %} tag. I'm also passing the 'csrfmiddlewaretoken' back in the ajax post. This no longer works in firefox either, but I think the methodology is improving as this method seems to work for him :/. I've updated the question's code snippets to be in line with the current implementation

'
'ORIGINAL QUESTION BELOW
'

I'm a beginner when it comes to Django and web dev in general and I'm trying to set up a simple app. Essentially, what I want to do is have an input box and a button. When the button is clicked, the contents of the input box are posted back to the server using ajax and caught by a view. I'll then play around with the contents of the input box in the view and send back a simple json object. The code:

HTML

```
<div class="input-text">
                Enter the Map ID provided to you by ... below
            </div>

            <form onsubmit="return false;">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="text" id="map-id-input">
                <button id="map-id-btn" class='btn btn-default custom-btn' onclick="checkMapID()">
                    Go 
                </button>
             </form>
```

JavaScript

```
function checkMapID() {
var mapId = $("#map-id-input").val();
$.ajax({
    url: "check_map_id/", 
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json", 
    data: {
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
        map_id: mapId,
    },
    success: function(status_dict) {
        if (status_dict.status === 1) {
            $("#status").html("Valid map ID <br> Loading Data...")
            window.location = status_dict.url;
        }
        else {
            $("#status").html("Invalid map ID. Please try again, or contact MRCagney")
        }
    },
    error: function(result) {
        console.log(result)
    }
});
```

}

Django URL

```
url(r'^check_map_id/$', views.check_map_id),
```

Django View

```
@ensure_csrf_cookie
def check_map_id(request):
map_id = request.POST['map_id']

if map_id not in GEOJSON_LOOKUP.keys():
    status = json.dumps({
        'status': 0,
        'url': '',
    })  
    return HttpResponse(status, content_type="application/json")
else:
    status = json.dumps({
        'status': 1,
        'url': reverse('map', args=(map_id,)),
    })
    return HttpResponse(status, content_type="application/json")
```

This is really all there is to what I'm trying to do. I should say, that I ahve added the required code (as defined in the django docs) to set the ajax header:

```
function getCookie(name) {
var cookieValue = null;
if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
        // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
        if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
            cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
            break;
        }
    }
}
return cookieValue;
}

var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
$.ajaxSetup({
    crossDomain: false, // obviates need for sameOrigin test
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
```

This is working nicely in Firefox, but in Chrome I get a 403 error whenever I click the button. The error is:

```
Object {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, 

setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}
abort: function (a){var b=a||u;return c&&c.abort(b),x(0,b),this}
always: function (){return e.done(arguments).fail(arguments),this}
complete: function (){if(h){var c=h.length;!function g(b){n.each(b,function(b,c){var d=n.type(c);"function"===d?a.unique&&k.has(c)||h.push(c):c&&c.length&&"string"!==d&&g(c)})}(arguments),d?f=h.length:b&&(e=c,j(b))}return this}
done: function (){if(h){var c=h.length;!function g(b){n.each(b,function(b,c){var d=n.type(c);"function"===d?a.unique&&k.has(c)||h.push(c):c&&c.length&&"string"!==d&&g(c)})}(arguments),d?f=h.length:b&&(e=c,j(b))}return this}
error: function (){if(h){var c=h.length;!function g(b){n.each(b,function(b,c){var d=n.type(c);"function"===d?a.unique&&k.has(c)||h.push(c):c&&c.length&&"string"!==d&&g(c)})}(arguments),d?f=h.length:b&&(e=c,j(b))}return this}
fail: function (){if(h){var c=h.length;!function g(b){n.each(b,function(b,c){var d=n.type(c);"function"===d?a.unique&&k.has(c)||h.push(c):c&&c.length&&"string"!==d&&g(c)})}(arguments),d?f=h.length:b&&(e=c,j(b))}return this}
getAllResponseHeaders: function (){return 2===t?e:null}
getResponseHeader: function (a){var b;if(2===t){if(!f){f={};while(b=ic.exec(e))f[b[1].toLowerCase()]=b[2]}b=f[a.toLowerCase()]}return null==b?null:b}
overrideMimeType: function (a){return t||(k.mimeType=a),this}
pipe: function (){var a=arguments;return n.Deferred(function(c){n.each(b,function(b,f){var g=n.isFunction(a[b])&&a[b];e[f[1]](function(){var a=g&&g.apply(this,arguments);a&&n.isFunction(a.promise)?a.promise().done(c.resolve).fail(c.reject).progress(c.notify):c[f[0]+"With"](this===d?c.promise():this,g?[a]:arguments)})}),a=null}).promise()}
progress: function (){if(h){var c=h.length;!function g(b){n.each(b,function(b,c){var d=n.type(c);"function"===d?a.unique&&k.has(c)||h.push(c):c&&c.length&&"string"!==d&&g(c)})}(arguments),d?f=h.length:b&&(e=c,j(b))}return this}
promise: function (a){return null!=a?n.extend(a,d):d}
readyState: 4
responseText: "↵<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html lang="en">↵<head>↵  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">↵  <meta name="robots" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE">↵  <title>403 Forbidden</title>↵  <style type="text/css">↵    html * { padding:0; margin:0; }↵    body * { padding:10px 20px; }↵    body * * { padding:0; }↵    body { font:small sans-serif; background:#eee; }↵    body>div { border-bottom:1px solid #ddd; }↵    h1 { font-weight:normal; margin-bottom:.4em; }↵    h1 span { font-size:60%; color:#666; font-weight:normal; }↵    #info { background:#f6f6f6; }↵    #info ul { margin: 0.5em 4em; }↵    #info p, #summary p { padding-top:10px; }↵    #summary { background: #ffc; }↵    #explanation { background:#eee; border-bottom: 0px none; }↵  </style>↵</head>↵<body>↵<div id="summary">↵  <h1>Forbidden <span>(403)</span></h1>↵  <p>CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.</p>↵↵↵  <p>You are seeing this message because this site requires a CSRF cookie when submitting forms. This cookie is required for security reasons, to ensure that your browser is not being hijacked by third parties.</p>↵  <p>If you have configured your browser to disable cookies, please re-enable them, at least for this site, or for &#39;same-origin&#39; requests.</p>↵↵</div>↵↵<div id="explanation">↵  <p><small>More information is available with DEBUG=True.</small></p>↵</div>↵↵</body>↵</html>↵"
setRequestHeader: function (a,b){var c=a.toLowerCase();return t||(a=s[c]=s[c]||a,r[a]=b),this}
state: function (){return c}
status: 403
statusCode: function (a){var b;if(a)if(2>t)for(b in a)q[b]=[q[b],a[b]];else v.always(a[v.status]);return this}
statusText: "FORBIDDEN"
success: function (){if(h){var c=h.length;!function g(b){n.each(b,function(b,c){var d=n.type(c);"function"===d?a.unique&&k.has(c)||h.push(c):c&&c.length&&"string"!==d&&g(c)})}(arguments),d?f=h.length:b&&(e=c,j(b))}return this}
then: function (){var a=arguments;return n.Deferred(function(c){n.each(b,function(b,f){var g=n.isFunction(a[b])&&a[b];e[f[1]](function(){var a=g&&g.apply(this,arguments);a&&n.isFunction(a.promise)?a.promise().done(c.resolve).fail(c.reject).progress(c.notify):c[f[0]+"With"](this===d?c.promise():this,g?[a]:arguments)})}),a=null}).promise()}
__proto__: Object
```

Is there something simple I'm missing here?

Many thanks for taking the time to read all of that!

Comment: if it works on firefox and not in chrome, then clean cache of both and check again :)

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work in this instance :/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Setting header worked for firefox, but not for chrome.
What i did:

```
var fd = {};
fd['csrfmiddlewaretoken'] = $.csrf_token;
```

Where `fd` is the form data I send via AJAX.
`$.csrf_token` is the global object, I define it printing token to template.

After that (headers+form data) everything works fine.
Note: i have another approach in several situations, where I'm emulating data that I send to be like form.

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', $.csrf_token);
```

You can try this too.
(in this case you should add `processData: false, contentType: false,` to AJAX request settings.)

One more thing: I think you should use jquery.cookie plugin instead  of defining own function.

Comment: Is fd['csrfmiddlewaretoken'] = $.csrf_token; The same as:

csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken,  where var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');?

Comment: At header settings you should get token from cookies. For form data i get it, writing token to js variable using templates.

Answer (score 0):

Although the problem isn't fixed I think I have found the cause. In my local machine, printing out the csrftoken variable yields a token in the console. However, on my live version, no matter the browser, the token is not printed out and instead it's set to null. The code is in a script at the top of my template:

```
function getCookie(name) {
var cookieValue = null;
if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
        // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
        if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
            cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
            break;
        }
    }
}
return cookieValue;
```

}

```
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
console.log(csrftoken)

function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
```

I'll set up a new question for why this is happening (as I have no idea!)